# ImageField doesnt work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.7

When i try to upload file it gives me template error, that its required to fill in. Code:
models:

```
class ahoja(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='smayat')
```

forms:

```
class ahojaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ahoja
        exclude = ()
```

view:

```
def testview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # pokud form byl odeslan
        form = ahojaForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # formular s daty
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() #vytvoří událost
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/hlavni_stranka/kalendar/') 
    else:
        form = ahojaForm() # prázdný formulář
    return render(request, 'hlavni_stranka/test.html', {'form': form,})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is the `enctype` attribute in your template. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.